# Do not show the thumbnail row on Woocommerce product page if the product only has 1 image available

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I have products that contain 1 image (featured image) and other products that have the main featured image as well as additional images added in the gallery.

On the product page, how can I hide the thumbnail row that is display just under the main image but for products that only have 1 image and in the same time keep showing the row in case the product has multiple images.

When viewing a product that has only the main featured image added with no other images in the gallery the product page displays the main image as well as a small thumbnail of it in the thumbnail zone below it. I find this is redundant and the thumb is not needed if it's the only image available. Especially on mobile it looks awkward to display the main image and the same image below it as a thumb

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

It will remove thumbnail image if it has only one.

```
function woocommerce_remove_featured_image( $html, $attachment_id ) {
    global $post, $product;

    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
    
    if ( ! $attachment_ids ) {
        return $html;
    }
    $featured_image = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
    if ( is_product() && $attachment_id === $featured_image ) {
        $html = '';
    }
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html','woocommerce_remove_featured_image', 10, 2 );
```